# How do I turn on light mode in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, chromebook, lightmode

I'm trying to switch to light mode in my Gmail app on my chromebook because it eats up all my toner when printing. You can't contact google and I can't find anything on the internet. Does anyone have an solution on where to find the settings for dark/light theme?

Comment: You should not be printing like that. Instead, go into the email you want to print, and click the print symbol in the upper right. This will print the email content properly, not the email viewer.

Comment: Also, if you want to contact Google for help, you can sign up for [Google One](https://one.google.com/about/plans) for $1.99 per month, which gives you additional Google Drive storage and the ability to talk live with Google support.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

1. Open Gmail and log in.
2. Click the gear-shaped Settings icon, located toward the top-right corner of the screen.
3. Next to Theme, choose View all.
4. Scroll down and select the default or light theme.
5. Hit Save.